# Stripe Checkout Session issue

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using `stripe-php` to use stripe functionalities,

Below code works fine in localhost but not in server

My Code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiVersion("2020-08-27");

    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create(array(
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => array(array(
            'price_data' => array(
                'product_data' => array('name'=>'Eshop'),
                'unit_amount' => 1500,
                'currency' => 'gbp',
            ),
            'quantity' => 1,
        )),
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'success_url' =>  'https://example-success.com',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example-cancel.com',
    ));
    }
    catch (\Stripe\ErrorObject $e) {
          echo($e->getMessage());die();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo($e->getMessage());die();
     }

echo var_dump($session);
die();
```

Just blank page comes no error nothing, but works fine in localhost!!

Please anyone help me

Comment: So go and check what the error log has to say then.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following at the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and run that on your server, this should display any error output that is occurring. You *also* may want to change your catch blocks to the following in order to help you debug this further:

```
catch (\Stripe\ErrorObject $e) {
  var_dump($e); die("\r\nCAUGHT STRIPE ERROROBJECT\r\n");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e); die("\r\nCAUGHT GENERAL EXCEPTION\r\n");
}
```

as the exception being throw might not have a message set (it should be, but that is not actually required so the message could be missing resulting in the blank page being displayed), and calling the var_dump() will show you the entire Exception object which may help you diagnose this further.

Good luck!